# Criar barra de endereço a partir de uma string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como posso fazer para o javascript criar uma barra de endereço com html a partir de uma string? exemplo:

```
string: "D://Media/Musicas/"
```

como quero que fique

```html
<div class="address_bar">
    <label>
        <button class="dir" value="D://">D://</button>
        <button class="list">-></button>
    </label>
    <label>
        <button class="dir" value="D://Media/">Media</button>
        <button class="list">-></button>
    </label>
    <label>
        <button class="dir" value="D://Media/Musicas/">Musicas</button>
        <button class="list">-></button>
    </label>
</div>
```

Tipo algo similar aos exploradores do windows ou linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o método split dá para dividir a string e depois criar os botões dinamicamente.

```
<div class="address_bar">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var path = "D://Media/Musicas";

    var arr = path.split(/\/\/|\//);

    $.each(arr, function(i, val) {
        $(".address_bar").append("<label><button class='dir'>" + val + "</button><button class='list'>-></button></label>");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado, precisava de uma base para começar, se me permite, gostaria de implementar seu código para adicionar os valores dos diretórios ao botão

Comment: Ok. Este link tem informação sobre a licença no stackoverflow: [Licença MIT – Como utilizar códigos do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4685/licen%C3%A7a-mit-como-utilizar-c%C3%B3digos-do-stack-overflow)